# Parsing/formatting odd date formats with lubridate

Tags: r, string-formatting, lubridate

I am having some trouble formatting the following date with lubridate. I'm not married to the lubridate approach but can someone recommend a good way to format these wonky Sept dates?

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(y=1:5, Date=c("Sept 1 2002","Sept 7 2002","Sept 9 2002","Sept 20 2002","Sept 21 2002"))
```

I didn't really expect this to work:

```
df$Date2=mdy(df$Date)
```

But I do not understand why this one didn't work:

```
df$Date2=parse_date_time(df$Date, "%b %d %Y")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if we match the abbreviations as in `month.abb`.  One option would be to remove the 't' in 'Sept' using `sub`.

```
 mdy(sub('(...).', '\\1', df$Date))
 #[1] "2002-09-01 UTC" "2002-09-07 UTC" "2002-09-09 UTC" "2002-09-20 UTC" "2002-09-21 UTC"
```

and

```
month.abb
#[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

If we look at `?strptime`

> %b: Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform.
>   (Also matches full name on input: in some locales there are no
>   abbreviations of names.)

Comment: I always forgot about sub.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it seems that one can parse "Sept" (and not "Sep") using '%m', which I would have expected to work just with 09 or 9.

```r
sept <-  c("Sept 1 2002", "Sept 7 2002", "Sept 9 2002", "Sept 20 2002")
lubridate::as_date(sept, format = "%b %d %Y")
#> Warning: 4 failed to parse.
#> [1] NA NA NA NA
lubridate::mdy(sept)
#> Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
#> [1] NA NA NA NA
lubridate::as_date(sept, format = "%m %d %Y") 
#> [1] "2002-09-01" "2002-09-07" "2002-09-09" "2002-09-20"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>